# Сохранить пакеты в файл

Tags: linux, wireshark, сниффер

Использую `wireshark` версии 1.10.14 на `Centos 7.5`. Ввожу в консоль команду :

```
tshark -D
```

получаю корректный вывод, как мне сохранить его в файл ?

Пробовал так :

```
tshark -D > file.txt
```

и так

```
tshark -D -w file.txt
```

В первом случае файл создается но он совершенно пуст, во втором файл не создается вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте tee

```
tshark -D | tee file.txt
```

Comment: не совсем помогло. просто `tshark -D | tee file.txt` создавало вайл пустым, но я добавил sudo вот так -> `sudo tshark -D | tee file.txt` и это сработало!

Comment: @Сергей, так это скорее всего у вас прав на запись в каталог нет.